# Array#uniq for arrays of ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I recently stumbled upon [this](http://blog.kabisa.nl/2011/06/03/custom-arrayuniq-for-activerecord-results/) blog post, which states that Array#uniq behaves differently on arrays of ActiveRecord objects, but neither gives a specific example for it, nor does it tell the reason for this.

I would like to see a reproducible example of this the different behavior and an explanation for it.

**edit:**
I'm talking about Array#uniq, not ActiveRecord::Relation#uniq. If the latter one is what the above mentioned blog post actually means, then my question has been already been answered by loz (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active record 'arrays' are not arrays they are a different.  So (asside from .all, which explicitly returns an array) if you use associations or similar you get different behavior, as lazy loading is in operation:

```
post = Post.find(1)
post.comments
=> Array[Comment(:1), Comment(:2)]... etc
```

Looks like an array, but

```
post.comments.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

So performing Uniq operates on the relationship, which adds more constraints to the query which will eventually be run on the database when the records are required:

```
post.comments.uniq
```

This will perform the uniq by doing a DISTINCT or UNIQUE query clause in SQL, rather than doing uniq in ruby..

Uniq details are found here: [rails uniq documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-uniq), and you can see about what returns ActiveRecord::Relation in [active record here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database)

Comment: So if I put my ActiveRecord objects in a regular Array, everything would work as expected?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: By "Working as expected" I mean "behaving the same way as Array#uniq"

Comment: If you use `post.comments.to_a.uniq(...)` it will work as you expect.

Comment: The issue is whether you really want that.  The purpose is to ensure that your uniq doesn't loop through in Ruby if it can be done in the database.  If however your uniquness is based on methods you need to execute on the models themselves for comparison, then you will need to .to_a them